# "ERROR: npm v9.5.0 is known not to run on Node.js v18.15.0." on Windows using nvm

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I ran into "ERROR: npm v9.5.0 is known not to run on Node.js v18.15.0." on Windows using nvm.

```bash
nvm -v
# Running version 1.1.7.
```

Answer (score 9):

> Update to latest nvm [(currently 1.1.10)](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases/tag/1.1.10) by
> downloading and running `nvm-update.exe`.
> You might need to do `nvm off` before update.
>
> ```bash
> nvm -v
> # Running version 1.1.10.
> ```
>
> So retry install newer node:
>
> ```
> nvm install 18.15.0
> nvm use 18.15.0
> npm -v
> # 9.5.0
> ```
>
> Now npm does not throw

<sub>*This content was part of the [initial revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75781350/1) of the question; the answer was not posted separately as it should have been as a Q&A. The content has been migrated from the question to an answer, as the OP has not responded to comments to do so.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: npm v9.8.0 is known not to run on Node.js v12.18.2. This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.

Answer:

1. Install latest version of Node using NVM
2. Uninstall node from control panel
3. Install version 12.18.12 using `nvm install 12.18.2`
4. `nvm use 12.18.2`